# Is it safe keeping Supee patch files in root?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

As question asks, is it safe to keep old patch files in root folder even after they are installed?
Can these patches somehow be initiated or uninstalled without SSH access?

Answer (score 2):

No, they cannot. If any attacker would be able to execute these files remotely to undo the patches, they would be able to execute *any* code and then you are in trouble anyways, no matter if the files are there or not.

The only risk that I see is that an attacker could determine by the files, which patches are applied and by exclusion which are not applied. But there are other ways to figure that out, so the only way to be safe is to always apply new patches as soon as possible.

Comment: I guess I can keep them in Root folder for future reference without worrying much.

Comment: @Icon if you only keep them for future reference then the `app/etc/applied.patches` file in the only file you need and you can get rid of the patch files ;)